# Typescript React useCallback eslint force typed arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I'm trying to force correct typings on all `useCallbacks` in react with typescript and eslint.
By default the arguments defined in `useCallback` are of type `any`.

```js
// @types/react
function useCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(callback: T, deps: DependencyList): T;
```

What this means is that both typescript and typescript-eslint's `no-explicit-any` rule doesn't pick this up (as it's defined as `any`).

So if I write the following code:

```js
const callback = React.useCallback((value) => {
  ...
}, []);
```

I would like either typescript or eslint to throw me an error as `value` is any here.

Is there an eslint plugin that can handle this for me? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: We faced the same issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly I did not

Answer (score 0):

You can type the function manually, I don't know about any automations that could help you here:

```
const callback = React.useCallback<(value: string)=>void>((value)=>{
  // value should be typed as string now
}, []);
```

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that I (and my colleagues) don't *have* to

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I didn't find a rule which would prohibit the usage of `any` type. To mitigate the problem, we ended up making the rules around usage of any as strict as possible with this set of rules:

```
// eslint setinngs rules:
"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
"@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call": "error",
"@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "error",
"@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument": "error",
"@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "error",
```